# JavaScript: how to select class A inside class B inside id X when there are two class B elements?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I need to access a class using JavaScript document.querySelector. How can I access a class (.btnCancel) inside a class (.formBox) inside an id (#add-occasion), when there are two similar named .formBox classes inside the #add-occasion id? I have lots of modals with the same class names for buttons and different modal ids.

```
<div data-role="modal" id="add-occasion">
    <h3>Add new occasion</h3>
    <form>
        <div class="formBox">
            <input type="text" id="new-occ" value="" placeholder="" class="" />
        </div>
        <div class="formBox">
            <input type="button" class="btnCancel" value="CANCEL" />
            <input type="button" class="btnSave" value="SAVE" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `document.querySelector("#add-occasion .formBox .btnCancel")` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is this:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#add-occasion .formBox .btnCancel");
elements[0].style.border = "1px solid red";
```

Since there is only one element that meets all three of those criteria, it will only return one element.  The `querySelector()` function will look in both `.formBox` elements, but won't find a `.btnCancel` element in the first one so it will just move on to the next `.formBox` where it will find one.

---

In fact, with the HTML you show, you don't even need the `.formBox` reference and could just use this because there are no `.btnCancel` items outside of a `.formBox` that you're trying to avoid:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#add-occasion .btnCancel");
elements[0].style.border = "1px solid red";
```

---

Or, if you're sure there's only one element that might meet your criteria or you only want the first one, then you can just use `document.querySelector()`:

```
var item = document.querySelector("#add-occasion .btnCancel");
item.style.border = "1px solid red";
```